# alignment of textboxes & labels in a JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jsp, dialog

I am unable to align the labels and inputs in a JQuery dialog within a div. I am unable to use `<td>` as then the code of the dialog gets displayed in the JSP page directly instead of in the dialog.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the relevant HTML and CSS (if any)? Consider creating a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.com) to show what you have so far.

Comment: I am unable to add the code, the website cutting it in a strange way.

Comment: How about a JSFiddle? We won't be able to help you without seeing the relevant HTML.